# What is the meaning of "a big chain wants to buy them out"?

Tags: meaning

In Crime movie *Before the Devil Knows You're Dead (2007)*, Andy is telling to Hawk about bank robbery plan on their own parent's
store and also people leaving near to it may identify him.

> Andy: We own a lot of land in the mall, and I'm getting a lot of big
>   handshakes. "Andy, baby, how are you?" "I haven't seen you in so long
>   since you left." And telling me all that bullshit because they figure
>   I'm making a killing, because **a big chain wants to buy them out**. I'm
>   saying someone's going to just recognize me too easy.
>
> Hawk: So we postpone, just...
>
> Andy: Yeah, we could, you know, wait a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chain is a single company that has multiple stores or restaurants. Examples of ***big chains*** are Best Buy, Target, and McDonalds. To ***buy someone out*** is to purchase someone's property or company, or someone's share of ownership. For example, someone who owns 75% of a business could "buy out" the remaining 25% if his business partner wants to sell it. In this movie, Andy is describing how he owns "a lot of land" in a mall, which is a little vague. It's not clear if he owns a lot of stores in the mall or just the real estate property. So it's not clear to me whether the big chains want to buy his business or just the real estate -- but it's one of those two things.